# jq find value corresponding value from other key

Tags: curl, json, jq

I have a output of curl | jq:

```
{
  "ssh_keys": [
    {
      "id": 30482248,
      "fingerprint": "21:57:08:d8:41:0f:89:57:0b:96:95:64:ff:59:50:69",
      "public_key": "ssh-rsa AAAA vyacheslav@MacBook.local",
      "name": "User's key"
    },
    {
      "id": 30450573,
      "fingerprint": "27:0c:2e:34:63:00:13:9d:5c:26:44:15:f0:cf:15:13",
      "public_key": "ssh-rsa AAAA-VirtualBox",
      "name": "test1"
    },
    {
      "id": 30485316,
      "fingerprint": "28:63:11:6b:a0:c7:ae:e1:e7:98:0b:01:96:c2:f4:87",
      "public_key": "ssh-rsa AAAA lessons",
      "name": "rbm-mykey"
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "pages": {
      "last": "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account/keys?page=3",
      "next": "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account/keys?page=2"
    }
  },
   "meta": {
     "total": 59
  }
}
```

I want to return "public_key" that have value with "User's key" from "name" key, so the result should be

```
"ssh-rsa AAAA vyacheslav@MacBook.local"
```

I tried the command:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer " "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account/keys?page=1" | jq '.[] | .[] | .name'
```

But recieved only values of "name" key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jq` to select the `public_key` entry for the array element of the `ssh_keys` array that have a `name` equal to `User's key` (where string `User's key` is given by a value imported into the `jq` variable `$queryname` on the command line):

```bsh
jq -r --arg queryname "User's key" '.ssh_keys[] | select(.name == $queryname).public_key'
```

The `-r` makes the value be printed decoded.  Without `-r`, you'll get a JSON-encoded (and quoted) value back.

You would pipe the JSON output of `curl` through the above command.  With the given document as input, this would generate the single line

```
ssh-rsa AAAA vyacheslav@MacBook.local
```

Comment: This worked! thanks