# Curl not receiving bash variable and exits with jq error

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I want to pass bash variable in to curl request in bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#request sshkey from do rebrain account
do_token=`echo "var.do-token" | terraform -chdir=/input console -var-file terraform.auto.tfvars`
echo $do_token
curl -X GET -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $do_token" -d '{ "job_run": {} }' "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account/keys?page=1" | jq -r --arg queryname "User's key" '.ssh_keys[] | select(.name == $queryname).public_key'
```

`echo $do_token`  returns appropriate token in quotes like this:
`"token"`. But it throws an error `"jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)"`.

Then I passing it into main.tf:

```
data "external" "fetchssh" {
  program = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_sshkey.sh"]
  query = {
    do_token = var.do-token
  }
}
```

to use data.external.fetchssh variable in terraform

How should I implement it to avoid error?

Comment: You're pointing out that `echo $do_token` outputs the token _in quotes_.  Should the quotes really be part of the token?

Comment: @Kusalananda, well, when I manual puts token in quotes in curl, it works

Comment: Note that the shell does _quote removal_ as a step in the processing of the command line. So if you put quotes around the token on the command line, the quotes will not actually be part of the token.  It's like the difference between `echo "token"`, `echo token`, and `echo '"token"'`.  Only with the last `echo`, `token` will be output with quotes around it (and the single quotes will have been removed). I seriously doubt that your token should actually contain quotes.

Comment: Quote the "`'`" using backslash "`\`": `"User\'s key".

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @waltinator The single quote in `User's key` is not an issue. It's escaping it would do the wrong thing. If it needs escaping, `jq` would take care of it automatically (which is why I wrote it as an imported value like that in my answer to the OP's [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653639/116858)).

Comment: This worked `"${do_token//\"}"`

Answer (score -1):

This worked "${do_token//"}"
so passing it into `curl -X GET -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${do_token//\"}" "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account/keys?page=1" | jq -r --arg queryname "User's key" '.ssh_keys[] | select(.name == $queryname).public_key'` will return ssh key